# How to create a multi column multi row table without borders in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I just want to create a table like this
[image]

but without the in-between line among rows. I also don't need the line between columns like this
[image]

but below the Existing Methods CFNeT multi-column i need a line which doesn't span the full table. I mean that the line must fit into the content.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: You might want to look at the `booktabs` package.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP not respond to received answer more than one and half years.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  This a multirow and multicolumn table
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       a & b & g\\
       \hline
       b & c & h\\
       \hline
       g & v & a\\
       \hline
   \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `|` represent the vertical lines separating each element of the cell and `c` is the option to centre the cell's content (there are others like `r` -> right and `l` -> left).

Finally `\hline` stands for horizontal line. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: THe OP clearly states in their question that they want a table "without the in-between line among rows. I also don't need the line between columns like this enter image description here". The example code in your answer produces a table with a lot of horizontal and vertical rows. Also your table does not make use of `\multirow` or `\multicolumn`.  Could you please comment on that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile at least twice with every change in the percentage (last) column (since it uses [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbo) for getting the appropriate alignment).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
  margin=1in,
  landscape
]{geometry} % Just for this example

\usepackage{booktabs,collcell,eqparbox,makecell}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \newcommand{\pa}[1]{\eqmakebox[CFNetvsNeuMF][r]{#1}}% Percentage alignment
  \newcommand{\hlc}{\textbf}% Highlight cell
  \caption{Comparison results of different methods in terms of NDCG@10 and HR@10.}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{9}{c} >{\collectcell\pa}c<{\endcollectcell} }
    \toprule
    &
    &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Existing methods} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{CFNet} &
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
    Dataset & % \raisebox{.7\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Dataset}
    Measures & % \raisebox{.7\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Measures}
    ItemPop & eALS & DMF & NeuMF &
    CFNet-rl & CFNet-ml & CFNet &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\smash{\makecell[b]{Improvement of \\ CFNet \emph{vs.} NeuMF}}} \\
    \midrule
    ml-1m &  HR  & 0.4535 & 0.7018 & 0.6565 & \hlc{0.7210} &
      0.7127 & 0.7073 & \hlc{0.7253} &
      0.6\% \\
          & NDCG & 0.2542 & 0.4280 & 0.3761 & \hlc{0.4387} &
      0.4336 & 0.4264 & \hlc{0.4416} &
      0.7\% \\
    \addlinespace
    lastfm &  HR  & 0.6628 & 0.8265 & 0.8840 & \hlc{0.8868} &
      0.8840 & 0.8834 & \hlc{0.8995} &
      1.4\% \\
           & NDCG & 0.3862 & 0.5162 & 0.5804 & \hlc{0.6007} &
      0.6001 & 0.5919 & \hlc{0.6186} &
      3.0\% \\
    \addlinespace
    AMusic &  HR  & 0.2483 & 0.3711 & 0.3744 & 0.3891 &
      0.3947 & \hlc{0.4071} & \hlc{0.4116} &
      5.8\% \\
           & NDCG & 0.1304 & 0.2352 & 0.2149 & 0.2391 &
      \hlc{0.2504} & 0.2420 & \hlc{0.2601} &
      8.8\% \\
    \addlinespace
    AToy &  HR  & 0.2840 & 0.3717 & 0.3535 & 0.3650 &
      0.3746 & \hlc{0.3931} & \hlc{0.4150} &
      13.7\% \\
         & NDCG & 0.1518 & \hlc{0.2434} & 0.2016 & 0.2155 &
      0.2271 & 0.2293 & \hlc{0.2513} &
      16.6\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
% new
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text,
             table-format=1.4}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{Comparison results of different methods in terms of NDCG@10 and HR@10.}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                               l c 
                          *{7}{S} 
                               S[table-format=2.1,
                                 table-space-text-post=\%]<{\%} }
    \toprule
    &   & \mcc[4]{Existing methods} 
            & \mcc[3]{CFNet} 
                &  \mcc{\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Improvement of \\ 
                                              CFNet \emph{vs.} NeuMF}}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
Dataset & Measures  
        & {ItemPop} & {eALS}    & {DMF}     & {NeuMF} 
        & {CFNet-rl}& {CFNet-ml}& {CFNet}   & \mcc{}        \\
    \midrule
 ml-1m  &  HR       
        & 0.4535    & 0.7018    & 0.6565    &\B 0.7210  
        & 0.7127    & 0.7073    &\B 0.7253  &   0.6         \cr
        & NDCG      
        & 0.2542    & 0.4280    & 0.3761    &\B 0.4387  
        & 0.4336    & 0.4264    &\B 0.4416  &   0.7         \cr
    \addlinespace
lastfm  &  HR  
        & 0.6628    & 0.8265    & 0.8840    &\B 0.8868
        & 0.8840    & 0.8834    &\B 0.8995  &   1.4         \cr
        & NDCG 
        & 0.3862    & 0.5162    & 0.5804    &\B 0.6007  
        & 0.6001    & 0.5919    &\B 0.6186  & 3.0           \cr
    \addlinespace
AMusic  &  HR  
        & 0.2483    & 0.3711    & 0.3744    & 0.3891 
        & 0.3947    &\B 0.4071  &\B 0.4116  &   5.8         \cr
        & NDCG 
        & 0.1304    & 0.2352    & 0.2149    & 0.2391 
        &\B 0.2504  & 0.2420    &\B 0.2601  &   8.8         \cr
    \addlinespace
AToy    &  HR  
        & 0.2840    & 0.3717    & 0.3535    & 0.3650 
        & 0.3746    &\B 0.3931  &\B 0.4150  & 13.7          \cr
        & NDCG 
        & 0.1518    &\B 0.2434  & 0.2016    & 0.2155 
        & 0.2271    & 0.2293    &\B 0.2513  &   16.6        \cr
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]